# How to make GRUB remembers what I boot last time?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot

I am having Windows and Ubuntu installed side by side. So every time when I boot (when the GRUB menu appears)  I have to press *down* key to select a specific OS.

I want to edit the code of GRUB so that it remembers what I boot last. Like if I boot Ubuntu last time, then by default selected option will be Ubuntu in menu, similarly for windows.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to set `save_default` in `/etc/default/grub` (at the top of the file is OK):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

After adding these two lines  to `/etc/default/grub`, you then need to update Grub's configuration using this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

This should add the line `savedefault` at the end of each entry in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.